# @Media print doesn't work on chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, printing

How can I remove the page links?

Tried with everything I found and nothing works.

Tried with both

```
@media print {
 a[href]:after {
  content: none !important;
 }
}
```

And

```
@media print {
 @page {
  size: auto;
  margin: 0mm;
 }
}
```

And the result is the same. Made all my other `<link />` to `media="screen"` so Chrome eventually will recognize the print but still nothing. Is there a way to hide that?

I'm using Chrome version **66.0.3359.139 (Official Build) (64-bit)**

[image]

I know I can remove them with the settings on the left, but I don't want the user to do that every time.

Comment: If by "the page links" you mean the texts the browser prints itself (like the page number etc), that's outside of the scope of the HTML document and not under control of any CSS or JavaScript.

Comment: Actually it is possible. I made an hidden `iframe` and the content in it is getting fetched from an html file, where I have `style` tag and placing `@page { size: auto; margin: 0 } body { margin: 1.6cm }` worked.